# Improving code for learning purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three tabs and I want to navigate when I click on each one of them. The code that I wrote is working just fine, but I believe that is bad coding, there is any way to improve this is just for learning purposes. Thanks!!!!

```
jQuery(".nuestra_actualidad li:eq(0)").click(function() {
            jQuery("#tabs-actualidad").css("display","block");
            jQuery("#tabs-articulos").css("display","none");
            jQuery("#tabs-noticias").css("display","none");
        });
 jQuery(".nuestra_actualidad li:eq(1)").click(function() {
            jQuery("#tabs-actualidad").css("display","none");
            jQuery("#tabs-articulos").css("display","block");
            jQuery("#tabs-noticias").css("display","none");
        });

 jQuery(".nuestra_actualidad li:eq(2)").click(function() {
            jQuery("#tabs-actualidad").css("display","none");
            jQuery("#tabs-articulos").css("display","none");
            jQuery("#tabs-noticias").css("display","block");
        });
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: loop using each funtction

Comment: maybe you should give class to the tabs like 1, 2, 3
and create function the show tab by class and hide the others

Comment: See jQuery functions show and hide.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Replacing jQuery with $ if possible (unless it clashes with another library) and then it can be reduced to a single function by utilising the index of the clicked element and calling the toggle function:

```
$(".nuestra_actualidad li").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("#tabs-actualidad").toggle(index === 0);
    $("#tabs-articulos").toggle(index === 1);
    $("#tabs-noticias").toggle(index === 2);
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/gSKeL/